# How to use nested for-loops to produce multiple combination of rows with NAs in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, missing-data

```
replicate <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
level <- c("low","low","mid","mid","low","low","mid","mid","up","up","up")
high.density <- c(14,54,82,24,12,11,12,NA,40,NA,20)
low.density <- c(36,31,10,NA,28,45,17,24,10,5,2)

df <- data.frame(replicate, level, high.density, low.density)
```

The data looks like the following

```
replicate level high.density low.density
    1     low    14          36
    1     low    54          31
    1     mid    82          10
    1     mid    24          NA
    2     low    12          28
    2     low    11          45
    2     mid    12          17
    2     mid    NA          24
    2      up    40          10
    2      up    NA           5
    2      up    20           2
```

I am trying to create data-sets where I make various combinations between high.density and low.density with NAs. Rule: I can only have combinations for same replicate and level. So each data-set will be unique in those positions. For instance,

```
replicate level high.density low.density
    1     low    14          36
    1     low    54          31
    1     mid    82          NA #only 1 change
    1     mid    24          10 #only 1 change
    2     low    12          28
    2     low    11          45
    2     mid    12          17
    2     mid    NA          24
    2      up    40          10
    2      up    NA           5
```

Next data-set

```
replicate level high.density low.density
    1     low    14          36
    1     low    54          31
    1     mid    82          10 #original dataset
    1     mid    24          NA #original dataset
    2     low    12          28
    2     low    11          45
    2     mid    NA          17 #only 1 change
    2     mid    12          24 #only 1 change
    2      up    40          10
    2      up    NA           5
    2      up    20           2
```

Next iteration

```
replicate level high.density low.density
    1     low    14          36
    1     low    54          31
    1     mid    82          NA #change here
    1     mid    24          10 #change here
    2     low    12          28
    2     low    11          45
    2     mid    NA          17 #change here
    2     mid    12          24 #change here
    2      up    40          10
    2      up    NA           5
    2      up    20           2
```

Edit: For replicate 2, "up" the iterations should look like the following. Only two combinations are possible.

```
2      up    NA          10
2      up    40           5
2      up    20           2

2      up    40          10
2      up    20           5
2      up    NA           2
```

Even though I could not manage to get the thing running myself, I think the `for` loops should be of the following form:

```
for(i in seq_len(dim(df)[1])) {
  for(j in seq_len(length(df$replicate))) {
    for(k in seq_len(length(df$level))) {
      if(!is.na(df$high.density)) | is.na(df$low.density))
    }
  }
}
```

Could anyone provide some direction?

Comment: Is what you need a list of all possible permutations in high.density and low.density when the group `replicate` + `level` contains `NA`?

Comment: Do you want to have all possible unique combinations `if(!is.na(df$high.density)) | is.na(df$low.density))` AND `if(!is.na(df$low.density)) | is.na(df$high.density))`?

Comment: @Dion No. For instance, I don't want to make changes for replicate `2` `low`. Those values are already paired, so I don't want to make any changes there.

Comment: What should happen with `2`/`up`? It has three values, one of which is `NA`.

Comment: @r2evans I have edited the question to include that possibility.